# Asp.net designer.cs is always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I know that this question has been posted a few times but I've tried every answer in those without finding a solution.

My problem is that none of my controls (in a specific aspx file) is showing in the designer file. This makes it hard to access some of the controls from the code-behind.

**What I've tried:**

- Tried just saving the .aspx file to regenerate the designer file. (nothing happens)
- I've deleted the designer file and pressed "Convert to web application". Which gets me back my designer file. But it's still empty.
- Tried removing all the code and saving then pasting the code back in (no success)
- Tried changing Codebehind="" to CodeFile="" and back again with no success.

What am I missing?!

I'm on Visual Studio 2013, latest version.

**Aspx file**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"  MasterPageFile="Framework/Email.master"   Inherits="OrderConfirmationEmail1" EnableViewState="false" Codebehind="OrderConfirmationEmail1.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="Content" runat="server">
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <web:UsePage  runat="server" StructureLevel="1">            
                <web:PageLink runat="server">
                    <site:UseWebsiteSettings runat="server">
                        <web:Image runat="server" MaxWidth="200" Name="Logotype1" />
                    </site:UseWebsiteSettings>
                </web:PageLink>
            </web:UsePage>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font: bold 16px Arial, Sans-serif;"><web:Text runat="server" Name="Title" /></td>
                    <td style="font: bold 16px Arial, Sans-serif; text-align: right;"><web:Text runat="server" Name="OrderNumberLabel" />&nbsp;<Ecom:OrderID runat="server"></Ecom:OrderID></td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td bgcolor="#f6f6f6" style="font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;"><strong><web:Text runat="server" Name="DeliveryTitle" /></strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                        <Ecom:DeliveryRepeater runat="server">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <Ecom:FirstName runat="server" />
                                <Ecom:LastName runat="server" /><br/>
                                <Ecom:Address1 runat="server" />
                                <Ecom:Address2 runat="server" /><br/>
                                <Ecom:Zip runat="server" />
                                <Ecom:City runat="server" /><br/>
                                <Ecom:Country runat="server" /><br/>
                                <Ecom:Phone runat="server" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </Ecom:DeliveryRepeater>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
            </table>
            <%// Order rows %>
            <Ecom:OrderRowRepeater runat="server" OnItemDataBound="OnOrderItemDataBound" OnItemCreated="OnOrderItemCreated" RenderEmpty="True">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#f6f6f6" style="font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                                <strong><web:Text Name="OrderProductsColumnTitle" runat="server" /></strong>
                            </td>
                            <td  bgcolor="#f6f6f6" style="text-align: right;font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                                <strong><web:Text Name="OrderQuantityColumnTitle" runat="server" /></strong>
                            </td>
                            <td  bgcolor="#f6f6f6" style="text-align: right;font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                                <strong><web:Text Name="OrderPriceColumnTitle" runat="server" /></strong>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="#f6f6f6" style="text-align: right;font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                                <strong><web:Text Name="OrderTotalColumnTitle" runat="server" /></strong>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </table>
                </FooterTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <strong><PC:DisplayName runat="server" /></strong>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <Ecom:OrderRowQuantity runat="server" />
                    &nbsp;<web:Text runat="server" Name="OrderRowQuantityAbbreviation"/>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <Ecom:OrderRowHasCampaign runat="server">
                                <OnTrue>
                                    <Ecom:OrderRowCampaignPrice DisplayCurrencySymbol="true" runat="server" />
                                </OnTrue>
                                <OnFalse>
                                    <Ecom:OrderRowListPrice runat="server" DisplayCurrencySymbol="true" />
                                </OnFalse>
                            </Ecom:OrderRowHasCampaign>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <Ecom:OrderRowTotalPrice DisplayCurrencySymbol="true" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </Ecom:OrderRowRepeater>



            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <web:Text Name="OrderRowDiscountTitle" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <Ecom:OrderTotalDiscountAmount DisplayCurrencySymbol="true" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <web:Text Name="OrderRowDeliveryMethodTitle" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <Ecom:DeliveryMethodDisplayName runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <Ecom:OrderTotalDeliveryCost DisplayCurrencySymbol="true" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <web:Text Name="OrderRowPaymentMethodTitle" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <Ecom:PaymentMethodDisplayName runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <Ecom:OrderTotalFee DisplayCurrencySymbol="True" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="grandtotal">
                        <td style="font: 18px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <web:Text Name="OrderRowTotalTitle" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; font: 18px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <Ecom:OrderGrandTotal DisplayCurrencySymbol="true" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <web:Text Name="OrderRowWhereOfVATTitle" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right; font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                            <Ecom:OrderTotalVAT DisplayCurrencySymbol="true" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>


            <web:ValueExists ID="TrackingContainer" runat="server" Name="TrackingUrlInformation">
                <OnTrue>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="TrackingLink" runat="server" CssClass="tracking-link" Target="_blank"><web:Text runat="server" Name="TrackingUrlText"/></asp:HyperLink>

                    <div style="padding: 20px 0; font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                        <web:Text Name="TrackingUrlInformation" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </OnTrue>
            </web:ValueExists>

            <web:ValueExists runat="server" Name="Text1">
                <OnTrue>
                    <div style="padding: 20px 0; font: 14px Arial, Sans-serif;">
                        <web:Text  Name="Text1" runat="server" />
                    </div>
                </OnTrue>
            </web:ValueExists> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<web:Text runat="server" Name="OrderRowQuantityAbbreviation" Visible="false"/>
```

**Solved**

Not sure what I did but eventually it worked. Sorry, for anyone in the same position.

Comment: Can you post code to your aspx page please so that we can know a little more about your issue and help you a little better

Comment: Ive just tried a test webforms application and my designer file was also blank until i built the solution.  Have you tried to build it and then look at the designer?

Comment: I've added the aspx code above.
I've rebuilt a lot of times.

Comment: using your code, and building the solution I get this `protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink TrackingLink;` in my designer file, but thats all.  Do you get this is it still blank?

Comment: All I did get was blank.
But now it seems to be working after not working for about 2 days...
Not sure what I did that solved it.

Comment: have you upgraded to Window 10? I have and its causing all sorts of issues with Visual Studio 2015 for me